# A way to minify or uglify ES6 Template Strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

Something like

```
var tpl = `
<div> 
   template
   <span>string</span>
</div>
`
```

Will produce:

```
var tpl = "\n<div> \n  template\n  <span>string</span>\n</div>\n";
```

What I need is to get rid of extra spaces and maybe line breaks, like all other html minification tools do.

So it should become similar to:

```
"<div>template<span>string</span></div>"
```

Are there any ways to achieve this wisely and indestructible?

Comment: use regex replace \r\n or \n, \s+, \t+ with '\n', '\s', '\t'

Comment: But this minification does alter your program, and the appearance of your page (notice the whitespace before the span)?! There's no sane way to do that without explicit annotations, and then it's just a question of string processing.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler?

Comment: I am using TypeScript, but I don't think it's a matter of a transpiler.
Of course it could be a function processing string, which would delete spaces (probably one won't be able to define for sure, which are the real spaces and which are not) and line breaks.  I am just looking for the most clever way to achieve it.

Comment: If this a filesize concern then gzip compresses all the whitespace and linebreaks quite well, the redundancy simply doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is probably using a tagged template, like

```
var tpl = minifyHTML `
<div> 
   template
   <span>string</span>
</div>
`;
```

You can start with

```
function minifyHTML(parts, ...values) {
    var out = [];
    out.push(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i<parts.length; i++)
        out.push(parts[i], String(arguments[i]));
    return out.join("");
}
```

which is basically the same as with no tag.

Now you can extend that to minify the `parts` of the template dynamically, so that the `tpl` will become the expected string.

The next step is to introduce this as a static optimisation in your compile pipeline. Figure out how to write a rule that matches tagged template expressions in the AST where the tag is the identifier `minifyHTML`, and then evaluate your minification as a part of compiling/bundling the ES6/TypeScript source to the distributed files.